# copy link only in command window (Windows command prompt)

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

I would like to copy a file as a linmk to a diffferent directory is it possible in the command window to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to decipher your message, but I suspect that you are looking for [**junction.exe**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768).

Comment: Junction is only for folders.

Comment: Oh yeah, so it is.

Answer (score 1):

For files in XP, you are looking for hardlinks.  Junction only does folders.  In XP, you'll need to use the **fsultil hardlink create** *destinationName* *sourceFileName*

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 7 (and I presume Vista), `xcopy` accepts a new `/b` switch that, according to the help `"Copies the Symbolic Link itself versus the target of the link.`

Comment: Symlinks do not exist in XP. Only Vista+